# Multi Table Join adding columns SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

Table1

```
ID      FID    DID
1       91     9
2       92     9
3       34     862
```

Table2

```
FID      Office Name
9        CompABC
862      CompXYZ
```

Table3

```
FID       TotalInvoice
91        850
91        450
91        450
92        450
34        300
34        325
```

The results from the query I am trying to achieve are like so

```
9    CompABC 2200
862  CompXYZ 625
```

I have tried something like

```sql
Select SUM(t3.TotalInvoice) as InvoiceTotal
,t2.[Office Name]
from Table2 t2
inner join table1 t1 on t2.FID = t1.DID
inner join table3 t3 on t1.FID = t3.FID
```

DID are actually entities of Table1 so a full list would include itself.

I am getting improper results here any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
select t2.FID, t2.[Office Name], SUM(t3.TotalInvoice) 
from Table2 t2
join Table1 t1 on t2.FID = t1.DID
join Table3 t3 on t1.FID = t3.FID
group by t2.FID, t2.[Office Name]
```

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/66912/1/0 - you beat me to it, so I put your query in an sql fiddle.

Comment: Well I have tried several combinations, Thanks for your answer the I am getting different results however if I just Select SUM(t3.TotalInvoice) where FID = 9 is exactly "the amount of times 9 is in the FID field" divided by the Value I get when I run your query.

Comment: Hi.  I'm not sure what these problem is.  Check out the sqlfiddle in the comment Derek left.  The query works there.  Try to figure out what is different with your code or data.